A very sad short story about a man who worked in space and is unable to readjust to Earth
I read this story in a collection not so long ago, but it was in my previous life, that is, BC (before Covid). I think I read it in French but in that case it was certainly a translation from US English as it obviously takes place in the US.
Indeed, the POV character, early in the story, claims to be a Big Chief of one of the Amerindian tribes, Cheyenne, Apache, Comanche. I don't remember which, but he is drunk and obnoxious; no way to know if this is pure fabrication or whether he really does have some mixed origins (but his name is mentioned later and is quite European). This takes place in an intercity bus. The other people in the bus are exasperated, but somehow they tolerate him because everyone realises that he is one of those "spacers" who work long stints in space and have a hard time readjusting to Earth. He complains of suffering from the gravity. But people think it is mostly the alcohol.
He gets off the bus at some regular stop in the middle of nowhere (it reminded me of a famous scene in "North by Northwest) and starts walking towards the farm where his wife lives (IIRC, at her parents' farm). One understands that he has worked a long time in space, made good money but somehow, in the few days since he arrived, he had spent (or lost?  by gambling? he could not have drunk that much!) all of it and is afraid to meet his wife penniless.
Someone drives by and offers him a ride in his car. This is when we learn the man's name, because the driver recognised the name (also European) of his in-laws, and thus realised who he was. He drops him near the farm but the spacer is still so afraid to meet his wife and in-laws in this situation that he keeps tarrying. I don't remember the end, not sure whether he finally reaches the farm, tarries till he is eventually found by his in-laws or even dies just a short distance from the farm.
But in any case, the degradation of this poor man is really heart-wrenching.
I addd the "space" tag event though the entire story takes place on Earth, because the fact that the man worked a long stint in space is of paramount importance.

TIL: Affabulation.

It's not at all unusual for an American Indian to have a European name, e.g. Vice President Charles Curtis (1929-1933), 3/8 Indian, member of the Kaw nation, grew up on a reservation.

Edmond Hamilton's "What's it Like Out There?" is a classic sad short story about an ex-astronaut, but not the one you're looking for.

Whoops, I meant to write 'I added the "space" tag' in my edit but the letter 'e' is missing. Well, I guess someone else will add it if they find a reason to edit it for more than just 1 letter

Not all the details match up, but I immediately thought of "The Hoofer" by Walter M. Miller.

“The Hoofer” inhabits a similar future as “Death of a Spaceman” (1954) where space travel is a dangerous blue-collar occupation and coming home from the “Big Bottomless” parallels the traumas of a wartime veteran. With deceptive and powerful simplicity, “The Hoofer” follows Big Hogey Parker, with bottle of gin in hand that aggravates the physical symptoms of space travel–“glare-blindness, gravity-legs, and agoraphobia”, on his bus journey home a “week late”. He has a secret he fears to share with his wife. And the effects of space travel only explain some of his deep sadness within.


A good enough match for me !

The secret is he lost all the money he earned in this stint, but I don't remember how it happened. Is it explained in the story ?

@Alfred I read the story decades ago, and honestly I don't remember any of the details - just the atmosphere. You did a good job of evoking that atmosphere in your question, and I immediately thought of "that Walter Miller story".
